# Multiple Microservices readers/writers using the same Database table (Asking for Trouble??)

Tags: microservices

Warning this is an open ended question but I am curious about peoples opinions on multiple Microservices reading from the same table in a database.

I am currently working on a set of API's that exhibit a Microservice architecture but various endpoints need to read from the same table and there are a few background processes writing to the very same table.  This sounds like a bad architectural decision to me because no application team seems to own the schema due to multiple writers, if they want to make changes to it, then multiple code bases need to be updated.

My knowledge is fluffy on Microservices but this design decision sounds like an abuse of the Microservice architecture.

Comment: My answer to a similar question may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40221269/569662

Comment: How this had happened that several different writers could write into the same table? Who is responsible (in code) for the data that gets stored into the table?